# How to redirect my sub-domain to localhost:5000 in Https with Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, web

I've a problem with my nginx :

**I have to redirect all the http and https traffic when my users search "hermes.my-domain.com" to the 5000 port, on my nginx serveur, where my app is.**

"hermes" is the name of my sub-domain.

So I do that :

```
server {

listen    80;
server_name    hermes.my-domain.com;

return 301 https://hermes.my-domain.com$request_uri;
} 

server {

listen    443;
ssl_certificate           /etc/certs/ssl/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key       /etc/certs/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}
```

Every time I fall on a 502 error.

I don't understand what's happen...

if someone know the problem please ?

Thank you very much !

This is my result from error.log :

My apologies, this is my result from error.log :

```
    2021/11/24 09:09:44 [error] 19384#19384: *332 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.1.158, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "hermes.my-domain.com"

2021/11/24 09:09:44 [error] 19384#19384: *332 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.1.158, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:5000/", host: "hermes.my-domain.com"

2021/11/24 09:09:44 [error] 19384#19384: *332 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.1.158, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "hermes.my-domain.com", referrer: "https://hermes.my-domain.com/"
```

Thank you for your help all !

Comment: If that is an exact copy-paste, note that you currently have `location /{` and probably mean to have `location / {`. Often `nginx` will put something in `error.log` - maybe you could post if there is something there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I put a space between "/{" in my vhost file, but it's the same result. And I add a log output, and this is the result :                      
10.10.1.158 - - [23/Nov/2021:17:16:17 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36".

Comment: normally use `listen 443 ssl;` or `listen 443 ssl http2;` never read about ssl on

Comment: The output above is from `access.log`. Please edit the question and add contents of `error.log` when the error occurs.

Comment: `connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on port 5000. Make sure your service is running and listening on the correct port and interface. You can do that by running `ss -tnlp |grep :5000`.

Comment: Oh okay, so if I understand well, it's not my Vhost the problem, but rather my web app is not correctly working on my 5000 port ?

Comment: It's a possibility. We can't say for sure without seeing the output of said command.

Comment: The result is nothing, I do some test on other port what I know active, and I have a result, but for ss -tnlp |grep :5000, I have nothing. So I think you're right ! And the problem is more on my web app. Thank you so puch for your answer and help

Answer (score 1):

Your application server is not listening on Port 5000.

`connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on that port on that interface.

An empty output of `ss -tnlp |grep :5000` confirms that nothing is listening on that port.

If your application server is indeed running, check it's configuration for the correct port. If it is not running, start it.